# Convert jQuery Serialized URL to JSON Object

Tags: jquery, json, object, serialization

There are similar examples but they do not seem to address this specific problem. I have previously serialized a form with jQuery for AJAX processing. I wanted to use that same serialized form and convert it into a JSON object. The examples I found did not address removing all special characters added in the initial serialization. So I am posting this here and answering in hopes that it will be helpful and save someone the time I already spent. OR perhaps someone has something more elegant.

So, we have a serialized form:

```
Form1 = $('#MyForm').serialize();  // Name=Mr.+John+Mark+Jr.&Email=john%40example.com
```

What to do with it to achieve a workable JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 = $('#MyForm').serialize();  // Name=Mr.+John+Mark+Jr.&Email=john%40example.com
  Form1 = Form1.replace(/\+/g, '%20'); // Name=Mr.%20John%20Mark%20Jr.&Email=john%40example.com
  var Decoded = decodeURIComponent(Form1); // Name=Mr. John Mark Jr.&Email=john@example.com
  var Values = queryParamsToJson(Decoded); // { Name : "Mr. John Mark Jr.", Email : "john@example.com" }

  function queryParamsToJson(theURL)
  {
     var href = theURL;
     var qStr = href.replace(/(.*?\?)/, '');
     var qArr = qStr.split('&');
     var stack = {};
     for (var i in qArr)
     {
        var a = qArr[i].split('=');
        var name = a[0],
        value = a[1];
        if (name.match(/(.*?)\[(.*?)]/))
        {
           name = RegExp.$1;
           name2 = RegExp.$2;
           //alert(RegExp.$2)
           if (name2)
           {
              if (!(name in stack))
              {
                 stack[name] = {};
              }
              stack[name][name2] = value;
           }
           else
           {
              if (!(name in stack))
              {
                 stack[name] = [];
              }
              stack[name].push(value);
           }
        }
        else
        {
           stack[name] = value;
        }
     }
     return stack;
  }
```

Comment: I edited the script but please correct me if I am wrong. I have always understood, regarding scope in JavaScript, that one can only create a global by defining it outside of a function. The use of "var" will keep the scope inside the function should there be a global of the same name. Otherwise, that variable will affect the global. Although good practice, it is my understanding that declaring a variable inside a function without a preceding "var" does not create a global variable. ("Form1", as I stated, was previously defined.)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.